# How to comment a JS module pattern class using JSDoc3?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, module-pattern

That's the way I actually do this but the private methods and propertys are not visable after I generate the Documentation.

have I done something wrong?

Incidentally, everything else works fine. I use the first time a documentation generator, and I'm very impressed.

```
/**
 * Constructor Description
 * @constructor
 * @class
 * @classdesc Something about my class Foo.
 */
container.Foo = function() { this.init(); };
container.Foo.prototype = (function() {

  /**
   * @private
   * @name container.Foo~fooPropertyPrivat
   * @property {boolean} fooPropertyPrivat Some description
   */   
  var fooPropertyPrivat = true;

  /**
   * Some description
   * @private
   * @name container.Foo~doSomethingPrivat
   * @memberOf container.Foo
   * @method doSomethingPrivat
   */   
  function doSomethingPrivat() {
      //...
  }

  return {
    /**
     * @public
     * @name container.Foo#fooPropertyPublic
     * @property {boolean} fooPropertyPublic Some description
     */ 
    fooPropertyPublic: true,

    /**
     * Some description
     * @public
     * @constructs
     * @name container.Foo#init
     * @memberOf container.Foo
     * @method init
     */
     init: function() {
       //...
     }
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raphael, I'm glad to hear that JSDoc 3 is working well for you so far!

By default, JSDoc omits any symbol tagged with `@private`. You can override this setting by using the `--private` command-line option.